# Terminology for elements of a coset

Tags: group-theory, terminology

Suppose I take the left coset of a group $G$ with its subgroup $H$ with identity $e$. Let $|G/H|=4$. Let the cosets be named $H, aH, bH, cH$. What is terminology used to name the elements inside each of the cosets$H, aH, bH, cH$?

Will 'orbits of left multiplication of $H$ with $e,a,b,c$ be a good name? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: $xH = \{xh\mid h\in H\}$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux yes, so what is the name given to the set?

Comment: I think usually people just say "elements of the coset $aH$". If this doesn't suit your needs, as long as the fact that left multiplication/left cosets is/are being used, you could say something like "$a$ translates of (elements of) $H$".